# embed flutter module to android native

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-platform-channel

I have existing android app that's written in native . Right now I want to develop new feature to the existing app. 
I will develop module write in flutter and embed it to my existing app

the question is , if the flutter module need connect to external peripheral for example bluetooth printer or request data from external REST API .whether this can be done ?

Comment: you can do it by flutter plugin flutter-platform-channel, check code at this link: https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/battery

Comment: ok , thank you @DhawalSodhaParmar . so there is no issue if the flutter module to access external peripheral.

Comment: ofcourse, you can use it thru plateform-channel till any other way provide by flutter team.